# Convert pair of integers to tuples in Swift 4?

Tags: swift4

I have an array, each element of which is an array of two ints (like coordinate pairs):

```
`[ [1, 2], [2, 2], [11, 9], ... ]`
```

Elsewhere in my program there are places that need that info but as type Coord, which is defined as a tuple of `(x: Int, y: Int)`.

What would be the best way to iterate over each element in the array and convert it to Coord tuples of `(x: Int, y: Int)`?

Answer (score 0):

When you are sure that there exists only two objects in an internal array of main array, then you should try this

```
func getToupleFrom(arr: [Int]) -> (Int, Int) {
    return (arr[0], arr[1])
}
```

Then define a global var to store the tuples, if you need them all together.

```
var arrayWithTuple: [(Int, Int)] = []
```

Your example array can have these values and can be iterated like this.

```
let arrayInt: [[Int]] = [[1,2], [3,4]]
    for arr in arrayInt {
        arrayWithTuple.append(getToupleFrom(arr: arr))
}
```

Try it and share results

Comment: Thanks Bhavin, I'm trying to do this without a for loop though

Answer (score 0):

You don't need *to iterate*, use `map`

```
let array = [ [1, 2], [2, 2], [11, 9]]
let tuples = array.map { ($0[0], $0[1]) }
```

However this will crash if the number of items in the inner arrays is less than 2.

Comment: This doesn't work, perhaps because the Coord has specified names? Coord is defined as: typealias Coord = (x: Int, y: Int)

Comment: Aha, got it. Have to put the data in a Coord cast: let tuples = array.map { Coord( $0[0], $0[1]) }. Now it works!